# Safari ignoring .css('visibility', 'visible');

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I am using a post form in mvc, during post I want to show a hidden div (surprise).

I am usin js / jquery to show the div and it is working in all browsers except safari on mac :(

I am using the following right now

```
 $('#CreateForm').submit(function (e) {
    if ($("#CreateForm").find(".input-validation-error").length == 0) {
        window.setTimeout(HandleAnimation, 500);
    }
});

function HandleAnimation() {
    var loading = $("#loading");
    loading.css('visibility', 'visible');

    var loadininfo = $("#loading-info");
    loadininfo.css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

I found a post suggesting using the timeout, but that is ignored as well. Do you have a suggestion to use instead?

Thank you very much.

Comment: may be it will be okay to use `display: none;`

Comment: Please setup a fiddle that demonstrates the problem, so I can check on my Macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` instead of `visibility`.